# Running time of insertion into 2 hashtables with iteration and printing

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

I have a program that does the following:

Iterates through a string, placing words into a `HashMap<String, Integer>` where the key represents the unique word, and the value represents a running total occurrences (incremented each time the word is found).

I believe up to this point we are `O(n)` since each of the insertions is constant time.

Then, I iterate through the hashmap and insert the values into a new `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>`.  The `String` goes into the `List` in the value where the count matches. I think that we are still at `O(n)` because the operations used on `HashMap`s and `List`s are constant time.

Then, I iterate through the `HashMap` and print the `String`s in each `List`.

Does anything in this program cause me to go above `O(n)` complexity?

Answer (score 1):

That is `O(n)`, unless your word-parsing algorithm is not linear (but it should be).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using a Scanner and splitting the words with the built-in delimiter option.  Should that be linear?  Java docs unfortunately don't say (or at least I couldn't find it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, with a caveat. In a hash table, insertions and lookups take *expected* O(1) time each, so the *expected* runtime of your algorithm is O(n). If you have a bad hash function, there's a chance it will take longer than that, usually (for most reasonable hash table implementations) O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst-case.

Additionally, as @Paul Draper pointed out, this assumes that the computation of the hash code for each string takes time O(1) and that comparing the strings in the table takes time O(1). If you have strings whose lengths aren't bounded from above by some constant, it might take longer to compute the hash codes. In fact, a more accurate analysis would be that the runtime is O(n + L), where L is the total length of all the strings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.  I don't know what I can do except trust that Java's Hashing is efficient enough (I'm using standard library, not implementing my own).

Comment: @Dukeling- I don't think so. Each character will get processed at least one during the computation of the hash code (we hope!), and if the dispersion is high enough and random enough then all the remaining string comparisons should terminate pretty quickly. Therefore, I'd expect each character to get read a constant number of times for the O(n + L) runtime.

Comment: @templatetypedef I didn't read that properly. I assumed `L` is the average length, not the total length (if `A` is the average length, `nA = L`, thus `O(nA) = O(L)`).

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the two issues that Paul Draper and templatetypedef point out, there's another potential one. You write that your second map is a `hashmap < int,list < string > >`. This allows for a total linear complexity only if the implementation you choose for the list allows for (amortized) constant time appending. This is the case if you use an `ArrayList` and you add entries at the end, or you choose a `LinkedList` and add entries at either end.

I think this covers the default choices for most developers, so it's not really an obstacle.

Comment: My default choice would be a `LinkedList`, and adding to the end. Most library linked-list implementations, and Java's in particular are double-linked-lists, with a pointer to the end, thus also O(1) append. An `ArrayList` seems like an illogical choice if you're using only functionality that a `LinkedList` was made for - resizing the `ArrayList` isn't exactly free. Do any API `List` implementations (that support the operation) not support at worst amortized `O(1)` append?